# Test if BigDecimal can change integral part of other BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need a way to express that into valid java code: I have 2 `BigDecimals`, and I want to know if the smaller `BigDecimal` can (when added to the bigger `BigDecimal` once) change the integral part of the bigger `BigDecimal`. Example:

```
0.6; 0.4 ->true

0.6; 0.39 ->false
```

Is there any efficient way of doing that, or do I have to test?

Comment: When the smaller bigDecimal is added once to what?

Comment: to the bigger bigdecimal.

Comment: Why is one true and the other false? Can you express your requirement precisely?

Comment: Maybe you meant the non fractional part? In your example both examples change the fractional part of the bigger decimal, but only one changes the non fractional part. `0.6 + 0.4 = 1.0 , 0 -> 1` and `0.6 + 0.39 = 0.99 , 0 -> 0`

Comment: `Math.floor(numbA) != Math.floor(numbA + numB)`  should be ok

Comment: And can we please get out of the habit of referring to fractional parts as decimals? Every digit in both these numbers is a decimal. There is an integral part and a fractional part, and a decimal point. Come this question, I have now seen 'decimal' used to refer to all three. It's meaningless.

Comment: Sorry for my english, with decimal part I mean the part before the '.'. I thought thats how its called, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ah, its integral part. sorry for confusion.

Comment: If you only test one set of numbers, I would guess your best bet is to simply add them and check (as suggested by @Hacketo). If you have to test *lots* of smaller numbers with the same big number, you could calculate the threshold (`Math.floor(big)+1-big`) once and then compare each small number to that. Perhaps that would increase performance a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("0.90");
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("0.20");
if(b1.add(b2).intValue() > Math.max(b1.intValue(), b2.intValue())){
    System.out.println("The integral has changed");
}else {
    System.out.println("The integral is the same");
}
```

How the `intValue()` method works:

> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to the narrowing primitive conversion from double to short  ...
>   Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded ...

Comment: This doesn't work for very big numbers. Since the OP is using `BigDecimal` you have to account the possibility of very big non fractional part. An example would be `BigDecimal bigA = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE + ".90");`

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer after realizing Titus' answer was simpler. Credit goes to him/her.

```
 public static boolean integral(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {

    BigDecimal greater;

    if (a.compareTo(b) == 1) {
        greater = a;
    } else {
        greater = b;
    }

    BigDecimal sum = a.add(b);

    return (sum.intValue() != greater.intValue());
}
```

Comment: `charAt(0)` well ..,  `integral(new BigDecimal("13.39"), new BigDecimal("0.7"))` return false

Comment: when comparing strings, you have to use `equals` and not `==` or `!=`

Comment: No this do not work .. try with `integral(new BigDecimal("13.39"), new BigDecimal("0.1"))` should return false . BTW see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Oh. I've always been hesitant to use == but most of the time it worked fine. Thanks for that. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isNonFractionalChanged(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
    BigInteger aInt = a.toBigInteger();
    BigInteger aNewInt = a.add(b).toBigInteger();

    return aInt.compareTo(aNewInt) != 0;
}
```

The above works even for very big numbers.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.90");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.20");
System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + a.add(b) + " : " + isNonFractionalChanged(a, b));

BigDecimal bigA = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE + ".90");
System.out.println(bigA + " + " + b + " = " + bigA.add(b) + " : " + isNonFractionalChanged(bigA, b));
```